# dtruss on OSX 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos

I'm running OSX Mavericks. As I heard(WWDC 2013, 402-HD.mov) the clang compiler resides now here: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  29381728 Oct 23 08:40 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

In /usr/bin there's only a wrapper for clang(we can see that from the size):
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14224 Oct 22 21:25 /usr/bin/clang

I want to compile one simple C file with clang.
"clang main.c", and I get the a.out (0 errors, 0 warnings). All OK.

Now (the problem) I want to run dtruss on that command line: "sudo dtruss -f clang main.c" but I don't get an a.out. Why? (-f     follow children as they are forked). I would have expected that the wrapper does a fork and an exec to the real compiler, but it seems it's not if I run it with dtruss.

Comment: Does it work with `sudo` but without `dtruss -f`? I suspect the `sudo` is the actual culprit.

Comment: "sudo clang main.c" produces a.out

Comment: What happens if you pass `-v` to `clang`? Perhaps it will tell you what's happening? It may be writing the output to another directory. Perhaps it's failing for some reason.

Comment: "sudo clang -v main.c" I get more info about what clang is doing, but when running "sudo dtruss -f clang -v main.c", I get the same output as "sudo dtruss -f clang main.c" (almost of course.. dtruss reports now other addresses(mmap files, stat structures, etc..), but the same syscalls). I tried to specify an output file with -o but it's not created when running with dtruss. What I found interesting is, if I use -a flag for dtruss, I see this line: "execve 1". But there is no call to execve reported above. For example if I look at "geteuid 2", I can match 2xcalls to geteuid.